# zoom out animation in splash screen in android?

Tags: android, animation, splash-screen

I have a requirement in which i have to give zoom out effect in splash screen. Please Suggest something. I have an idea that we can keep its animation in res/anim folder and use it in activity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this in Activity Java File :

```
FrameLayout mainFrame = ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.FrameLayout01));
        Animation hyperspaceJumpAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.hyperspace_jump);
        mainFrame.startAnimation(hyperspaceJumpAnimation);
```

Put this code under res > anim > hyperspace_jump.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shareInterpolator="false">
   <scale
          android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
          android:fromXScale="0.0"
          android:toXScale="1.4"
          android:fromYScale="0.0"
          android:toYScale="1.4"
          android:pivotX="50%"
          android:pivotY="50%"
          android:fillAfter="false"
          android:duration="700" />
   <set android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
      <scale
             android:fromXScale="1.4" 
             android:toXScale="0.8"
             android:fromYScale="1.4"
             android:toYScale="0.8" 
             android:pivotX="50%" 
             android:pivotY="50%" 
             android:startOffset="700"
             android:duration="400" 
             android:fillBefore="false" />
      <!-- <rotate 
             android:fromDegrees="0" 
             android:toDegrees="360"
             android:toYScale="0.0" 
             android:pivotX="50%" 
             android:pivotY="50%"
             android:startOffset="700"
             android:duration="400" />
          -->
   </set>
</set>
```

Answer (score 9):

yu can use the view animation in order to get the zoom effect.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
   <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="900">        
   </alpha>
    <set
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:startOffset="700">
     <scale
            android:fromXScale="0"
            android:toXScale="1"
            android:fromYScale="0"
            android:toYScale="1.0"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:duration="1000" 
           android:fillBefore="false"   
      />
   </set>
</set>
```

create an XML file in the animation folder under resource.And in the java file you must set the animation for the respective image.

```
Animation hyperspaceJump = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.hyperspace_jump);
image.startAnimation(hyperspaceJump);
```

Here my xml file name is hyperspace_jump.for more reference click [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html).