# How to make a splash screen that does not shrink when fading

Tags: android

I've followed the steps to make a splash screen as noted here: [How to implement splash screen in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025734/how-to-implement-splash-screen-in-android)

While the splash screen works, I noticed that my splash screen shrinks when it is fading into my main activity. That is, my splash screen starts off as taking the entire screen, and then shrinks into a smaller rectangle as it fades. This is really obvious as my splash screen has a dark background, while my main activity has a white background.

Is there any way to stop this from happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The real question is "how do I control my Splash Screen animation"?  Including zoom in, zoom out, *no* zoom, fade, rotate, etc.

Here's a good discussion:

- [zoom out animation in splash screen in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702931/zoom-out-animation-in-splash-screen-in-android)